# Make a panel use the exact space it needs and fill in the rest with another panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

I want to make a layout with two componenents in a vertical row.
The first component is an instance of my own class, ImagePanel, that extends Panel and shows an image, and I want it to take up the exact space that it needs to show the entire image. The remaining space should then be filled by the other component (in this case another Panel with a GridLayout). See the picture.

[image: The desired layout]

In Android you can do this by using the weight property, but I have not been able to find anything like that in Java, and I can´t see that any of the standard layout managers in Java would be suitable for this.

I tried putting the ImagePanel in BorderLayout.NORTH and the other panel in BorderLayout.CERNTER, but the second panel was then overlapping the image, so that didn't work.

I also thougth about using a GridLayout but the grid would not care about the size of the image, so I don't think that would work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @JBNizet Why not posting that as an answer. I find it the better then the 2 current answers

Comment: @Robin: you're right. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BorderLayout should work, provided the image panel's `getPreferredSize()` returns the correct dimension (i.e. the dimension of the image it displays).

Using a simple JLabel containing an ImageIcon and no text instead of your custom ImagePanel would do that for you.

Comment: Thanks! I can't belive it was that easy.

Answer (score 1):

The most powerfull layout in java is GridBagLayout. It has weightx and weighty properties, anchor, fill, etc.

By default, with GridBagLayout each component has all the necessary space to show fully. If you want the second panel to expand, it should be enough with weighty=0.0 in your image and weighty=1.0 in your other panel.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that you could do that in Java. Good to know, although JB Nizets soulution was simpler, so I accepted that answer. I will however look into the GridBagLayout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.swing.Box` should be exactly what you want. There are 2 types of boxes, vertical and horizontal, you need a vertical:

```
Box box = Box.createVericalBox();
box.add(comp1);
box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5)); // add some empty space
  .
  .
  .
add(box);
```

`Box` will only force one side to be equal, for vertical, it's the width, the length could be any size.